# ASP.NET button on a web control has click event, but isn't recognized by control

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

For an old ASP.NET project I am working on, we have a user control with a button...

```
<%@ Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Codebehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyControl" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>

<!-- SNIP: Unrelated HTML tags... -->
<asp:button id="btSubmit" OnClick="btSubmit_Click" runat="server" style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: black" tabIndex="32" Text="View"></asp:button>
```

Since upgrading to .NET 4.0, whatever platform we try to run this on, we get the following error:

**Compiler Error Message:** CS1061: 'ASP.MyControl_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'btSubmit_Click' and no extension method 'btSubmit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.MyControl_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

...yet in the code behind:

```
// Class is defined as a partial, between MyControl.ascx.cs and MyControl.designer.ascx.cs
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    // This is defined in the designer code...
    protected Button btSubmit;

    // This is defined in the main code behind...but it IS defined.
    protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // SNIP: Functionality that works.
    }
}
```

I've tried the following things to resolve this issue:

1. Ensuring that the markup is valid
2. Ensuring that the C# code has no compilation errors.
3. Double-checked the control Razor tag to ensure that `autoeventwireup` is true, and `Codebehind` and `Inherits` are properly set.
4. Checked to ensure that my button control isn't colliding with the button click event.
5. Re-associated the button to the click event in Design mode, per suggestion.

Also of note: this web project is being deployed to a web server via TeamCity.  This works correctly when ran locally through Visual Studio, but fails on the server.

**Question:** What exactly is even *causing* this Compiler Error?  This code looks right.  I can detect no flaw in it.

Comment: delete the function here. Go to the button in design view . double click to recreate it. your problem will be solved

Comment: @TusharGupta - Trying that out

Comment: Try to declare the class MyControl as partial and delete the protected Button btSubmit

Comment: @slfan - The @ is there in the actual source.  Good catch, though!

Comment: @TusharGupta - Sadly, that approach had no effect.  I was hoping that was the answer...but it's not this time.

Comment: please restart the visual studio. i m sure it will solve your problem

Comment: @TusharGupta - one additional problem with that: this is happening on a server, after TeamCity deployment.

Comment: @AndrewGray, did you resolve this issue? If so, please post your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution to my problem, oddly enough, was that my Build settings were off!  This code *is* completely sane!

As a tip, you'll want to do the following steps, as a diagnostic measure:

1. Right-click your solution, navigate to **Properties**
2. Expand **Configuration Properties**, click **Configuration**.
3. Ensure that all libraries that you need to build have the **Build** checkmark checked.

The reason this was failing is because DLLs didn't exist, because they weren't built in the first place; when the project as a whole tried to reference these non-existant DLLs it failed horribly with the above compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the code behind class as partial and remove the button declaration, because visual studio generates some code as well.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, create a new UserControl and copy-paste the code inside the class and the HTML.